# I want to add localStorage to my angularJS so it will save the image that I chose after refeshing the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need help to store my chosen image to localStorage but i don't know where to add it on my angularjs script  what I want is when i already chose a photo that I want, i like to save it on localStorage and will stay after i refresh or close the browser. Please Help! here is my script below...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZgbo.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlVi.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv5u8.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload Photo and store on localStorage using AngularJS 1.X</title>

    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>


    <style>
        img{width:200px; height:200px;}
    </style>enter image description here
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="plunkr">
    <div ng-controller="UploadController">
        <form>
          <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" ng-model="imageSrc">
          <!--  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple> -->
        </form>
        
        <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" />
          
      </div>
    </div>

        <script>

var app = angular.module('plunkr', [])
  app.controller('UploadController', function($scope, fileReader) {
    $scope.imageSrc = "";
    
    $scope.$on("fileProgress", function(e, progress) {
      $scope.progress = progress.loaded / progress.total;
    });
  });


  app.directive("ngFileSelect", function(fileReader, $timeout) {
    return {
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      link: function($scope, el) {
        function getFile(file) {
          fileReader.readAsDataUrl(file, $scope)
            .then(function(result) {
              $timeout(function() {
                $scope.ngModel = result;
              });
            });
        }

        el.bind("change", function(e) {
          var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
          getFile(file);
        });
      }
    };
  });

app.factory("fileReader", function($q, $log) {
  var onLoad = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
    return function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        deferred.resolve(reader.result);
      });
    };
  };

  var onError = function(reader, deferred, scope) {
    return function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        deferred.reject(reader.result);
      });
    };
  };

  var onProgress = function(reader, scope) {
    return function(event) {
      scope.$broadcast("fileProgress", {
        total: event.total,
        loaded: event.loaded
      });
    };
  };

  var getReader = function(deferred, scope) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoad(reader, deferred, scope);
    reader.onerror = onError(reader, deferred, scope);
    reader.onprogress = onProgress(reader, scope);
    return reader;
  };

  var readAsDataURL = function(file, scope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var reader = getReader(deferred, scope);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return {
    readAsDataUrl: readAsDataURL
  };
});
          
          
          </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the selected image, just save the image string to local storage:

```
function getFile(file) {
  fileReader.readAsDataUrl(file, $scope)
    .then(function(result) {
      localStorage.setItem('myImage', result);
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.ngModel = result;
      });
    });
}
```

Then you can retreive image from local storage by calling:

```
imageResult = localStorage.getItem('myImage')
```

Comment: awesome! it works perfectly ^^ i also added on my $scope.imageSrc after retreiving it and now i can view the image even if i refresh the page :)

Comment: anyway here is how I added.. '$scope.imageSrc = localStorage.getItem('myImage');'

Comment: @Jhoy Glad it works for you. Please accept the answer as correct one to help other to identify correct solutions.

Comment: finally i found the check button haha.. well done! thanks again!